# Sort by reference count in mongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, one-to-many

I have two documents :

Application (irrelevant to show), and scans :

```
{
  application_id: 'xxx'
}
```

I would like to get all the applications sorted by the number of scans.

With SQL, I would have done something among the lines of :

```
SELECT applications.*, COUNT(scans.*) as scans_count FROM applications
LEFT JOIN scans ON scans.application_id = applications.id
GROUP BY applications.id
ORDER BY scans_count
```

It seems that the aggregate framework of mongo does not allow this.

Some options :

#### Map / Reduce

Not sure if this is relevant here, map/reduce is kind of slow and I need the answer to be very fast.

#### Embed the scans document inside applications

Not possible because I need to access scans globally

#### Add a field to the applications document to keep track of the numbers of scans

This could work but if someday I want to count only some scans, depending on a condition, the problem will come again

I'm fairly new to mongodb, what is the best solution for my problem? Is my schema too relational ? If so, how can I make it better ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, most flexible, option is to do it in two steps:

1. An `aggregate` query on `scans` to get the `application_id` values and scan counts, sorted by count.
2. A `find` query on `applications` using `$in` to get the applications for those `application_id`s.

You can only query one collection at a time, so anything join-like requires either reworking your schema to get everything you need in one collection, or using multiple queries.

Comment: Additional question : How can I get all the applications if some applications have 0 scans ?

Comment: I can't get a sorted list with $in. I need to because i plan to add pagination after that.